# Ubuntu 18.04 uses just 2 GB of 16 GB RAM. Do I need to do something about it?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, memory-test

[image: screenshot with a various performance checking tools showing low RAM usage: free -h shows 15 G total, 1.5G used, 12G free]

I have 16 GB RAM, but my Ubuntu system just uses a maximum of 2 Gb!!?
What should I do about this, if anything?

Comment: Having free RAM is good. If all your RAM (and swap) is used, your system will hang and freeze.

Comment: Your system seems to be fine. It sees all 16G. And it'll only use as much memory as required. The rest goes to file/disk cache/buffers or available.

Comment: @heynnema your comment seems like the answer to me :)

Comment: As others have said, your system is running as expected. If you open more applications, you can use more RAM - you've got plenty. In your image, what I paid attention to was the amount of RAM and the Swap usage. Your swap is nil (and swap is *not* actually 'extra RAM when the system runs out', it's more complicated than that) and your free RAM is plentiful. You're in good shape. Open up a few browser instances and load heavy pages and it'll surely increase the amount of RAM you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your system seems to be fine. It sees all 16G. And it'll only use as much memory as required by the system, and running applications. The rest of memory goes to **file/disk buffers/cache** or **available**, when viewed with the `free -h` command.

total ~= used + free + buff/cache

available ~= total - used

Comment: thank you so much for your clarification.